# What does "past year" turn into in indirect speech?

Tags: reported-speech

1) I know that *last* changes to *previous* but what does *past* transform to for this example:

Direct Speech: Some strange things happened during the last/**past** year.

Reported Speech: On October 25, 1842, he said that some strange things had happened during the previous/**(?)** year.

I can change "the past year" with "the previous 12 months". Is there a better choice?

UPDATE:

2) I do not want to open a new topic. This is another question I have.

Text from 1881: "The two inventors are said to have increased the stability of their machine."

I made an attempt to convert the sentence above to, I do not know how to call this because it does not look to be pure reported speech, but I am not sure especially about "to have increased". Does its form change or not.

In 1881, the two inventors were said **to have increased** the stability of their machine.

Comment: *Last* and *past* in this context mean the same thing, so "the previous year"  or "the prior year" is fine for both.

Comment: I was told that "past year" means the last 365 days (October 26, 1841 - October 25, 1842) and "last year" is January 1 - December 31, 1841. Is it true?

Comment: *Last year* means in the 12 months prior to the most recent January 1, but *in the last year* means during the most recent twelve months. So right now, December 25 2016 (where I am), *it happened sometime **last year*** means sometime between 2015-01-01 and 2015-12-31, but *it happened sometime **in the last year*** means sometime between 2015-12-25 and 2016-12-25.

Comment: So "last year" changes to "previous year" and "past year" to ...?